# Using Stanford Parser(CoreNLP) to find phrase heads

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, phrase

I am going to use Stanford Corenlp 2013 to find phrase heads. I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768038/is-there-any-phrase-head-finder).

But, the answer was not clear to me and I couldn't add any comment to continue that thread. So, I'm sorry for duplication.

What I have at the moment is the parse tree of a sentence (using Stanford Corenlp) (I also tried with CONLL format which is created by Stanford Corenlp). And what I need is exactly the head of noun phrases.

I don't know how I can use dependencies and the parse tree to extract heads of nounphrases.
What I know is that if I have `nsubj (x, y)`, y is the head of the subject. If I have `dobj(x,y)`, y is the head of the direct object. f I have `iobj(x,y)`, y is the head of the indirect object.

However, I am not sure if this way is the correct way to find all phrase heads. If it is, which rules I should add to get all heads of noun phrases?

Maybe, it is worth saying that I need the heads of noun phrases in a java code.

Answer (score 8):

Since I couldnt comment on the answer given by Chaitanya, adding more to his answer here.

Stanford CoreNLP suite has implementation of Collins head finder heuristics and a semantic head finder heuristic in the form of

1. CollinsHeadFinder
2. ModCollinsHeadFinder
3. SemanticHeadFinder

All you would need is instantiate one of the three and do the following.

```
Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
headFinder.determineHead(tree).pennPrint(out);
```

You can iterate through the nodes of the tree and determine head words wherever required.

PS: My answer is based on the StanfordCoreNLP suite released as of 20140104.

Here is a simple dfs that lets you extract head words for all noun phrases in a sentence

```
public static void dfs(Tree node, Tree parent, HeadFinder headFinder) {
      if (node == null || node.isLeaf()) {
         return;
      }
      //if node is a NP - Get the terminal nodes to get the words in the NP      
      if(node.value().equals("NP") ) {

         System.out.println(" Noun Phrase is ");
         List<Tree> leaves = node.getLeaves();

         for(Tree leaf : leaves) {
            System.out.print(leaf.toString()+" ");

         }
         System.out.println();

         System.out.println(" Head string is ");
         System.out.println(node.headTerminal(headFinder, parent));

    }

    for(Tree child : node.children()) {
         dfs(child, node, headFinder);
    }

 }
```

Comment: The answer could get more intuitive if we could know what is the type of the `sentence` in `Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);` in your answer?

Answer (score 4):

You could extract the phrase of interest such that it is an object of the class [Tree](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html) You can then use [determineHead(Tree t)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/HeadFinder.html#determineHead%28edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree%29) method from any of the classes that implement the interface [HeadFinder](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/HeadFinder.html).