# Using Core Annotation vs. GrammaticalStructure / headWordNode

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using the Stanford CoreNLP to parse sentences. I am trying to create lexicalized grammar with sentiment and other language annotations.

I am getting a parse + sentiment + dep using:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, 
                  lemma, ner, parse, depparse, sentiment");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(mySentence);
```

Since I would like to use also dependencies in my grammar, I've been using `GrammaticalStructureFactory` and its `newGrammaticalStructure()` method to get a grammatical structure instance. I noticed that the 'TreeGraphNode' has a 'headWordNode' and thus, I traverse both trees in synchronization, e.g.

```
public void BuildSomething(Tree tree, TreeGraphNode gsNode) {
    List<Tree> gsNodes = gsNode.getChildrenAsList();
    List<Tree> constNodes = tree.getChildrenAsList();

    for (int i = 0; i < constNodes.size(); i++) {
        Tree childTree = constNodes.get(i);
        TreeGraphNode childGsNode = (TreeGraphNode) gsNodes.get(i);

        // build for this "sub-tree"            
        BuildSomething(childTree, childGsNode);
    }

    String headWord = gsNode.headWordNode().label().value();
    // do something with the head-word...

    // do other stuff...
}
```

And I call this function with the tree annotation and the grammatical structure root:

```
for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
    Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);
     GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(tree);

     BuildSomething(tree, gs.root);
}
```

Using something like the above code, I notice that the GrammaticalStructure I am getting does not necessarily matches the structure of the Tree (should it?) and also, I am getting sometimes a "weird" head selection (the determiner selected as head, seems incorrect):
[image: A parse with determiner as the head]

Is my usage of `GrammaticalStructure`/`headWordNode` is incorrect?

P.S. I've seen some code that uses 'HeadFinder' and 'node.headTerminal(hf, parent)' ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431754/using-stanford-parsercorenlp-to-find-phrase-heads/22841952#22841952)) but I thought that the other approach would be faster... so I am not sure if I can use the above or must use this approach

Comment: "the GrammaticalStructure I am getting does not necessarily match the structure of the Tree" — can you be more specific re: what you are expecting and what you are observing? The GrammaticalStructure and Tree representations correspond to different types of grammatical analysis, and there isn't always a one-to-one mapping between the results of the two analyses.

Comment: @JonGauthier - I was under the impression that they should match one-to-one though now I understand they won't. I was seeing mainly (didn't go deeply into it) different annotation on corresponding nodes (possibly also different tree structure). Is there a way to use the GS to find the head or should I use `HeadFinder`?

Comment: Yes, just use a `HeadFinder` instance directly. See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22841952/176075